# Matlab: sortrows with type cell

Tags: matlab

I import data to Matlab from Access via the function [`adodb_query`](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29615-adodb-tools?focused=3806020&tab=function) and transform them to a matrix via `Prices=[Prices.isin Prices.date Prices.prices]`. The result is a nx3-Matrix:

```
>> Preise(1:5,1:3) 

ans = 

  5×3 cell array 

    {'AT0000652011'}    {'29.12.2000'}    {[11.0900]} 
    {'AT0000720008'}    {'29.12.2000'}    {[ 5.0200]} 
    {'AT0000743059'}    {'29.12.2000'}    {[ 8.2000]} 
    {'AT0000746409'}    {'29.12.2000'}    {[10.8000]} 
    {'AT0000767553'}    {'29.12.2000'}    {[ 3.1700]}
```

As you can see, the data is sorted by column 2 (date) as it should be.
Now I´m using the function [`Pivot`](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26119-pivot-unpivot).

```
Pivot_P=Pivot(Preise);
Pivot_P(1:5,1:5) 

ans = 

  5×5 cell array 

    {[       NaN]}    {'AT0000652011'}    {'AT0000720008'}    {'AT0000743059'}    {'AT0000746409'} 
    {'27.02.2004'}    {[     26.1200]}    {[     10.7200]}    {[     12.9000]}    {[          12]} 
    {'28.02.2001'}    {[     12.9400]}    {[      5.2000]}    {[      8.7600]}    {[     12.5100]} 
    {'28.02.2002'}    {[     14.5600]}    {[      7.7700]}    {[      9.6800]}    {[      8.8200]} 
    {'28.02.2003'}    {[     14.4300]}    {[           9]}    {[      9.9700]}    {[      8.2300]}
```

Now I failed to convert the column with dates in Pivot_P with `sortrows(str2num(Pivot_P))`, `sortrows(cell2mat(Pivot_P))` and `sortrows(datetime(Pivot_P,format))`.

Unfortunately, I **have** to use `adodb_query` and `Pivot`. Does anybody have typical solutions?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? Also provide the sample input cell array accordingly

Comment: I want a pivottable like `Pivot_P`, just sorted for coloumn 1 (dates). What do you mean with "the sample input array"?

Comment: Provide a sample of exactly what you have. That we can put in our MATLAB as input. And provide exactly what will be the output for that input. Read how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: You might also want to look at `stack` and `unstack`, which might remove the need for the extra File Exchange function as they are MATLAB's built-in pivoting functions.

Comment: @SardarUsama when i´m trying to manually reproduce the first output, i don´t get type struct like the import. just "string" or "char".

Comment: @Wolfie I know. That´s why i wrote that i have to use it. i tried it with unstack but my prof wants to have it with pivot

Comment: You haven't written anywhere in your question the word "stack", I was just trying to be helpful

Comment: @Wolfie Yes you are right. I looked it up and tried to solve it with unstack. I worked quite good, but my professor wants to have it with `Pivot` :-/

Comment: Dr.   Ross Geller?   https://youtu.be/QcnogXICTeA